# Ajax call to Express server freezes the UI

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have a simple app where clicking on the button makes an Ajax call (asynchronously) to an Express server.

In the Express route handler, I simulate a long running operation by doing a loop (this is just a demo, in the future I intend to do a remote request to a Java REST API here).

The result is that the UI freezes here (the loading image does not even show during the time). Could you help me to spot the problem here ? 
Following is the code (I have tried with both POST and GET methods, still the same issue):

**Client**

```
$('#searchBtn').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'searchRepo',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#testDiv').html('');
            $('#loadingIc').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loadingIc').hide();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#testDiv').html('<div>Test</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

**Server**

```
router.get('/searchRepo', function (req, res) {
   sleep(10000);
   res.send('aaaaa');
});
function sleep(milliseconds) {
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
   if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `sleep()` simulation on the server is killing your server.  node.js is single threaded and thus a tight loop like that means that your server can do NOTHING else until that loop is done.  This is a poor simulation of a real remote request.  Use `setTimeout()` instead.  There is nothing here that would freeze the browser unless it was waiting for other files to be served by your server (CSS files, script files, etc...).

Comment: But I don't understand why when there is nothing happen on the client side. There should be at least the loading image showing, and things should not be freezed right ? And do you mean to setTimeout in the router code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, change your server code to:

```
router.get('/searchRepo', function (req, res) {
   setTimeout(function() {
       res.send('aaaaa');
   }, 10000);
});
```

As this more accurately simulates a long running remote request.

Second off, add an error handler to your ajax code so in case you're getting a timeout or some error, you will know that is happening.

Your version of `sleep()` was killing your single threaded node.js server so it could do nothing else for 10 seconds.  If your web page happened to be waiting on other resources to be served by the node.js server (style sheets, script files, etc...), it would get hung up waiting for your server to get unbusy.

I don't see anything else disclosed in your code that would "freeze" the browser.  You are using `async: true` which is required to keep from freezing the browser.  If `#loadingIc` is something visible, it should be visible during your ajax call.  You'd have to show more of the browser context for us to have an idea what else might be going on there.

Also, when you say "freeze" what exactly do you mean?  Are you seeing high CPU usage and complete non-responsiveness of any browser UI?  Or are you just not seeing the `#loadingIc` UI?  If it's the former, then your ajax call is probably not properly async.  If it's the latter, then there is probably a display problem with the `#loadingIc` UI.

Comment: I say "frezee" because I cannot click on other HTML elements on the page, so I find it very strange. And when the "Test" div appears on the page, the screen flickers a bit (like a synchronous call). I think I will try your setTImeout method first, thanks.

Comment: Yes, indeed after I tried your method, it's not freezing as I described anymore. But could you help me understand this more thoroughly ? In particular, I click the button to do ajax call when the page has fully loaded, so why the loop on the express route would block any other processing related to the client ?

Comment: @ramcrys - I don't know.  You aren't showing any client code that would cause a freeze.  There is apparently something else that is contacting the server while it was in the `sleep()` loop.  One guess would be that you are both submitting an Ajax call and submitting a form (if the search button is in a form) you may be submitting the form without realizing it and that was going to your blocked server.  If that's the case, then you need to `e.preventDefault()` in your submit handler to prevent the default form submission.  This could also explain why you don't see the results of the ajax call.

Comment: Indeed I have a form. My setup is very simple: form with a textbox and button, below is the div which contains "loadingIc" image.
Thanks a lot for your help, it clarifies a great deal.